# Ошибка "No module named" при импорте своего модуля в Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, импорт, модули, jupyter-notebook

Использую **Jyputer Notebook**

Сам путь, где расположены файлы с кодом - `C:\Users\user\oymau\parsing base\Selnm`

В папке Selnm есть два файла c кодом - **test** и **fync** (из которого хочу вызвать фун-ю **getdata**)

Собственно сама проблема - если я захожу в файл test и в нём ввожу

```py
import fync
```

пишет:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'fync'.

```py
from fync import getdata
```

даёт ту же ошибку

Сам fync содержит только одну функцию и всё.

```
sys.path[0] -- 'C:\\Users\\user\\oymau\\parsing base\\Selnm'
sys.version --- 3.8.8
```

буду благодарен за помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Notebook** просто не знает где искать Ваш модуль.

Попробуйте добавить путь к Вашему модулю в системную переменную PATH следующим образом:

```py
import os
import sys
module_path = "C:\\Users\\user\\oymau\\parsing base\\Selnm"
if module_path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(module_path)
```

**UPD:**

Скорее всего питон не ошибается и у Вас действительно нет соответствующего модуля по данному пути.

Если Вы сохраняли файлы через Notebook c форматом `ipynb`, Вы должны понимать, что это рабочий формат **Jyputer Notebook** и питон их никак не воспринимает.

Т.е питон ищет

```
C:\\Users\\user\\oymau\\parsing base\\Selnm\\fync.py
```

а у Вас

```
C:\\Users\\user\\oymau\\parsing base\\Selnm\\fync.ipynb
```

**Последний не является скриптом.**

Вам нужно создать текстовый файл `C:\Users\user\oymau\parsing base\Selnm\fync.py` и разместить там код, который Вы писали в Notebook, а потом уже пытаться импортировать его.

Comment: Михаил, благодарю с ответом, но к сожалению не помог - та же ошибка. Видите ли, у меня sys.path[0] -- 'C:\\Users\\user\\oymau\\parsing base\\Selnm' изначально. То есть интерпретатор изначально ищет модули с папки Selnm.

Comment: @БорисАстафьев, да. Этого я не заметил. Крайне интересно

Comment: Мне интуитивно кажется, что решение проблемы кроется в чём-то незначительном( Завис на этом этапе и всё)

Comment: благодарность большущая, очень сильно выручили

Comment: @БорисАстафьев, не за что) пишите еще